# почему не работает условие функции

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import*
root=Tk()
from random import*

def ssg():
   if i.get==2:
       lab['text']=random()

i=DoubleVar()


r4=Radiobutton(root,text='от 0 до 1',variable=i,value=2)
r4.grid(row=5,column=0, sticky='w')

but=Button(root,text='Сгенерировать случайное число',command=ssg)
but.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=3)

lab=Label(root,text='')
lab.grid(row=4,column=0,columnspan=3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if i.get==2:` здесь не поставлены скобки после get.
`if i.get()==2:` надо так